# Using jq to stream, filter large json file and save output as csv

Tags: json, parsing, filter, stream, jq

I have a very large json file I would like to stream (using `--stream`) and filter with jq, then save it as a csv.

This is the sample data with two objects:

```
[{"_id":"1","time":"2021-07-22","body":["text1"],"region":[{"percentage":"0.1","region":"region1"},{"percentage":"0.9","region":"region2"}],"reach":{"lower_bound":"100","upper_bound":"200"},"languages":["de"]},
{"_id":"2","time":"2021-07-23","body":["text2"],"region":[{"percentage":"0.3","region":"region1"},{"percentage":"0.7","region":"region2"}],"reach":{"lower_bound":"10","upper_bound":"20"},"languages":["en"]}]
```

I want to filter on the `"languages"` field in jq stream so I only retain objects where `languages==[“de”]`, then save it as a new csv file titled `largefile.csv` such that the new csv file looks like the following:

```
_id,time,body,percentage_region1,percentage_region2,reach_lower_bound,reach_upper_bound,languages
"1","2021-07-22","text1","0.1","0.9","100","200","de"
```

I have the following code so far but it doesn’t seem to work:

```
cat largefile.json -r | jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.))) | with_entries(select(.value.languages==[“de”])) | @csv
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are several separate tasks involved here, and some are underspecified, but hopefully the following will help you through the thicket:

```
jq -rn --stream '
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
  | select( .languages == ["de"] ) 
  | [._id, .time, .body[0], .region[].percentage,
     .reach.lower_bound, .reach.upper_bound, .languages[0]]
  | @csv 
'
```

Comment: I've checked the solution works using jq versions 1.5 and 1.6, as well as using gojq.  You probably mistyped something.  Try using the -f option.

Comment: it all works now, thanks a bunch! managed to stream, filter and turn into csv.